# Is an MCU typically programmed to leave some of its RAM unused?

Tags: c, embedded

It seems to me that MCU RAM holds linker values, globally scoped variables, heap, stack, and then some portion is unused.

As a result, do engineers tend to release firmware that leaves some chunk of MCU RAM unused as it is unneeded for the application to work?

Comment: wouldnt it be faster, better, more reliable to go to your manufacturer webpage and give a call to a client support? The answer to your question is Yes.

Comment: if your application/solution uses every bit of ram and flash that would be considered a bit of a failure, you need to design in some extra space for maintenance if nothing else.  It would be rare to have done the analysis to exactly measure the stack usage, and costly to try to track it real time and try to test to the point of failure.  You shouldnt need a heap, mallocs have no place in deeply embedded systems.  You leave some for the stack and for future maintenance or switch to a bigger part.

Comment: Seems a somewhat strange question.  What are you going to do with the RAM otherwise?  You cannot remove it, and a smaller part may be too small.

Comment: @Clifford I didn't find any resources to confirm what the answers below state, so I'm just doing my due diligence. I freely admit that it sounds obvious, and I bet the gist of these answers would be in low level textbooks about embedded development. My primary concern was that there could be a good reason to not expand the heap or stack to cover the unused space.

Comment: @Jase:  Actually I doubt that it would be specifically stated in any such text book.  Generally the memory available to a system is finite and fixed.  A design aim would be to design in enough to satisfy the project requirements, but not so much that your hardware costs increase for no benefit.  That is an intuitive economic and commercial issue, not a technical one.

Comment: @Clifford You can fill it with random peculiar data to confuse the copy cats? :)

Comment: @Lundin:  That would not confuse much.  Any serious prevention of IP theft would require far more robust techniques that that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the application.  In some cases, you might design some unused RAM in order to allow for future patches and growth.  In many cases, you would just take whatever is unused and use that to enlarge the heap or stack or some application specific buffers.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what I expected.

Answer (score 4):

When the hardware is selected or designed, it is unlikely that the development team will know precisely how much RAM will be required - it depends on the application, algorithms, data structures used, changes in requirements during development, and what compiler and compiler options are used.

Moreover memory devices come in specific discrete sizes, if your application required 28Kb of RAM, it is likely that you will choose at least a 32Kb part, because you will probably not find a 28Kb part!

Also it would be short-sighted to believe that RAM requirements will not change during maintenance of a project with software updates, so you need some headroom for that.  Your end users would not be impressed if you said they could have the bug-fix for the software, but to get it they need to change their hardware too!  In addition, the same hardware may be reused on a different, larger project, and reuse of hardware is even more cost effective that reuse of software.

In some cases, the linker might automatically allocate the heap to use all available memory not allocated for other purposes.  Where the heap is fixed however, it may be useful to leave some unused space, so that in maintenance, you may not have to re-size the heap every time non-heap memory usage increases.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the appplication and the controller.  Some controllers reserve specific ranges of RAM locations for, say, bootloader workspace or USB/IP buffer space.  Application segments placed in RAM also cover various ranges. Some code/data may be copied or mapped into RAM at startup, for example.

In all my embedded apps, all remaining spare space is just given over to the heap, (as suggested by @TJD).